# Rails enforce controller method is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In Rails, how can I enforce that a particular method is always called before performen an action on any controller?

For example, I want that a method called `can?('xxx')` for authorization check to be always called. If someone creates a new controller method and forgets to call this, I want to raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a before filter:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :require_login

  private

  def require_login
    can?('xxx')
  end
end
```

Docs: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters

Comment: Thanks Nerian, but some of the instance variables that are required for the can? are determined in the sub controller. And it is called on the object like @campaign.can?('view.ads')

Comment: You don't need to use ApplicationController. You can put this before filter in the controller where you need it; and use a method to get the current_campaign, for example.